# Index scrolling in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I want to display the ListView items in alphabetical order.
I also want to display the items with a separator.

If any one knows can you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways for ordering your ListView:

1. Use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and have your objects implement the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.
2. If you are using a Cursor to load your data (e.g. from a ContentProvider or database), you can use the SQL to order the data returned.

As for adding sections to your ListView, there are also 2 basic ways to do this.  Both methods are very well documented in this [blog post by Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/).